# How to run function in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

I have function, which is defined like below

```
function1 :: [Char] -> Int
function1 (x:s) | x=.........
```

How can I call this function in interpretator Hugs. I mean if I have function

```
function2 :: Int -> [Int]
function2 n | n < .........
```

I can call it in interpretator

```
function2 5
```

for example.

Thank you.

Comment: What you have written looks correct. What error do you get?

Comment: Hugs is old and unmaintained, use GHCi instead. (This is probably not related to any errors you're getting just sayin')

Comment: How to run it in interpretator?

Comment: It's exactly the same as calling any other function: `function1 "some chars"`

Comment: Can you give me some example?

Comment: @user1844845: Peter gave you an example.

Comment: @CatPlusPlus Stop with the Hugs bashing. It's faster than ghci, compiles Haskell 98 and has better error messages. It's the best interpreter for beginners.

Comment: @AndrewC No, it's just old and unmaintained

Comment: @CatPlusPlus It is old, it isn't maintained, but it is not bit rotten in the least, and is easier to understand than ghci. It is definitely better for teaching.

Comment: @AndrewC You have to learn how to use GHC/GHCi anyway to actually use Haskell so no I don't buy that. I don't find "here, learn this — you'll never use it again" to be a good teaching method. [This is not a discussion for comments anyway]

Comment: @CatPlusPlus You really think that someone who learned Hugs would find it hard to transfer those `:l MyModule.lhs`, `:r` and `myfunction input1` type interactions they learned to ghci? Were you aware that Haskell 98 is more-or-less a subset of the Haskell provided by ghc? Had it occurred to you that everything we teach on Hugs works __exactly the same__ in ghci, except the error messages are less helpful? First Hugs, second, ghc toolchain. You'll use it again if you're stuck with a sysadmin who's reluctant/slow to install something they don't understand, which in my experience is 5/6 of them.

Answer (score 4):

You would call it with a list of characters, also known as a String:

```
function1 "foo"
```

Comment: @user1844845: "Doesn't work" is really vague. This is how you call a function with the type you've given. If there is some *other* problem here, you'll need to tell us about it rather than just stating that "it don't works." What specific error are you getting?

Answer (score 2):

What Rein Henrichs said is correct, but are you sure you are loading the functions you wrote into the interpreter?

So if you saved your functions in `functions.hs` then start the interactive console (Hugs or GHCi) in the same folder as the file and type:

```
> :load functions.hs
> function1 "foo"
```